# Array of objects in js?

Tags: javascript

It's a silly question, but is this an array of objects in js?

```
var test = 
   { 
      Name: "John", 
      City: "Chicago",
      Married: false
   }
```

if so, how do I declare a new one..  I dont think

```
var test = new Object();
```

or

```
var test = {};
```

is the same as my example above.

Comment: To create a literal array you use brackets: `var test = [1, 2, 3];`

Comment: This may confuse you further, or it may make something click for you... this is an array w/ 1 object inside of it `var test = [{}];`

Comment: Yeh! it's a silly question!! why don't just google?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.
That's an object with three properties.

The object literal is just a shortcut for creating an empty object and assigning properties:

```
var test = { };   //or new Object()
test.name = "John";
test.city = "Chicago"
test.married = false;
```

Comment: Also sometimes called a map with three entries.

Answer (score 6):

An array of objects would be

```
myArray = [
    { prop1 : "val1", prop2 : "val2" },
    { prop1 : "A value", prop2 : "Another value" }
]
```

You would access the first object's `prop2` property like this

```
myArray[0].prop2
```

*"if so, how do I declare a new one?"*

To do what I think you want you would have to create an object like this

```
var test = function() { 
  this.name = "John"; 
  this.city = "Chicago";
  this.married = false;
}

var test2 = new test();
```

You could alter the properties like this

```
test2.name = "Steve";
```

You can create an array of your objects like this

```
myArray = [test, test2];

myArray[1].married = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it's an object.

You could create an array of objects like this:

```
var array_of_objects = [{}, {}, {}];
```

For creating new objects or arrays I would recommend this syntax:

```
var myArray = [];
var myObject = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `test` **is** an object. You can refer to it's instance variables like so:

```
var myname = test.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object, but you must also understand that arrays are also objects in javascript. You can instantiate a new array via `my_arr = new Array(); or my_arr = [];` just as you can instantiate an empty object via `my_obj = new Object(); or my_obj = {};`.

Example:

```
var test = [];
test['name'] = 'John';
test['city'] = 'Chicago';
test['married'] = false;
test.push('foobar');

alert(test.city); // Chicago
alert(test[0]);  // foobar
```

Comment: alert ( typeof new Array() ); // Object

Comment: @veidelis http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/